# Как удалить элемент из массива Pandas Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

У меня есть некоторое колличество xlsx документов с неогранниченным количеством листов, в разных документах могут встречаться дубликаты листов из предыдущих документов как на рисунке.
[image: дубликаты листов]

Как найти и удалить дубликат, не удаляя при этом всю строку или столбец?
Так как данные за Июнь 2020 и Май 2020 мне нужны.

```
def workHoursProc(workHoursFilePath,LOG_FILENAME):
logging.basicConfig(handlers=[logging.FileHandler(LOG_FILENAME,'a','utf-8')], level=logging.WARNING)
logging.warning(" \t"  + datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%H:%M:%S") + " workHoursProcessing.py - Start")
workHours = []
workHoursMonthNames = []
#listSheets = []
files=os.listdir(workHoursFilePath)
sheetList =[]
for file in files:
    workHoursProcessingSaveComments.createFile(workHoursFilePath, file)
    workHoursBook = xlrd.open_workbook(workHoursFilePath + '_' + file)
    workHoursMonthNames = workHoursBook.sheet_names()
    sheetList.append(workHoursMonthNames)
df = pd.DataFrame(sheetList)
```

Comment: Непонятно - что вы хотите получить на выходе? Что нужно откинуть, а что оставить? Приведите пример, например: входной датафрейм, отфильтрованный датафрейм, который вы хотите получить. Ну и желательно не только чтобы в скриншотах, а в воспроизводимом виде.

Comment: Я хочу чтоб у меня остались все элементы без дубликатов, т.е ИЮЛЬ 2019, ИЮНЬ 2019, МАЙ 2019, Sheet9, ИЮНЬ 2020, МАЙ 2020, dec2

Comment: Из того, что я вижу на картинке, `ИЮЛЬ 2019` -  это больше похоже на индекс строки датафрейма вообще-то (либо у вас там форматирование сильно съехало). Выглядит так, что вы вперемешку перечисляете индексы и значения, поэтому ничего непонятно. Приведите датафрейм в нормальном виде, не скриншотом, тогда может будет более понятно. Даже если это не индекс, то всё-равно непонятно - а где там данные, относящиеся к конкретному месяцу - в строках ниже? На скриншоте этого непонятно.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)